# JavaScript nested loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm doing an assignment using nested loop to ask user input information of 4 guess and print it out by alert. The problem is the `prompt` only repeat once.

```
var myArray = new Array(2);
for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess First Name.");
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Last Name.");
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Phone.");
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Address.");
    }
}
alert("first person : " + myArray[0][0]);
alert("second person : " + myArray[0][1]);
alert("third person : " + myArray[1][0]);
alert("fourth person : " + myArray[1][1]);
```

Comment: Look at the console. Which error do you see?

Comment: You have an array of two `undefined` elements, these aren't arrays and they don't have a `[0]` or `[1]` property. That's the problem.

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question: [`[javascript] multidimensional array`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+multidimensional+array). I'm pretty sure one of these would help you...

Comment: Please take a look at [the basics of JS arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) before asking for answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: What do you expect `myArray` to look like? Right not the data structure that would be created doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Just a quick note, do `myArray = []` instead because `new Array(2)` will create an array of size two but fill it with strange `undefined` values that unlike the normal `undefined` they can't be used with `.map` nor `.forEach`.

Comment: You are assigning the same prompt value to the same array element. `i` and `j` don't change between the different prompts...

Answer (score 3):

Try to change it to this:

```
var myArray = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    myArray[i]=[]; // <- this is what you're missing
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess First Name.");
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Last Name.");
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Phone.");
        myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Address.");
    }
}
alert("first person : " + myArray[0][0]);
alert("second person : " + myArray[0][1]);
alert("third person : " + myArray[1][0]);
alert("fourth person : " + myArray[1][1]);
```

Comment: What did you change and why? An explanation will be very helpful for any visitor.

Comment: I change exactly like amaksr and it only alert `myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Address.");`

Comment: @Scytheronix: You are calling `myArray[i][j] = prompt(...)` four times with the same values for `i` and `j`. Meaning that the forth assignment overwrites the first three. You first have to decide upon the data structure you actually want. Right now it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: While this answer solves the immediate problem, all the `myArray[i][j] = prompt(...)` are still wrong, logically. I don't think it deserves that many upvotes. That said, I also believe the question isn't that great.

Answer (score 0):

The code crashes after the first prompt because `myArray[i]` is not initialized.

Said that, I'll continue with a better answer:

The problem here is that the loop doesn't make sense.

At the end of the day the value of `myArray[i][j]` will be the input for "Guess Address".

```
myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess First Name.");
myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Last Name."); // overwrites previous assignment
myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Phone."); // overwrites previous assignment
myArray[i][j] = prompt("Enter Guess Address."); // overwrites previous assignment
```

In order to populate the arrays the way you want you will jave to just ask the four question without the loop:

```
myArray[0][0] = prompt("Enter Guess First Name.");
myArray[0][1] = prompt("Enter Guess Last Name.");
myArray[1][0] = prompt("Enter Guess Phone.");
myArray[1][1] = prompt("Enter Guess Address.");
```

**Note:** It may not be your case but in the general case it is better to have an object for that kind of data:

```
var guest = {};
guest.firstName = prompt("Enter Guess First Name.");
guest.lastName = prompt("Enter Guess Last Name.");
guest.phone = prompt("Enter Guess Phone.");
guest.address = prompt("Enter Guess Address.");
```

**Update:** Given that you insist with the nested loop initiative, I'll give you this option:

```
// nested array with the questions
var questions = [
    [ "Enter Guess First Name.", "Enter Guess Last Name." ],
    [ "Enter Guess Phone.", "Enter Guess Guess Address." ],
];

// initialize first-level array for the answers
var myArray = new Array(2);
for(var i=0; i<2; i++){
    myArray[i] = new Array(2); // initialize nested array at i
    for(var j=0; j<2; j++){
        myArray[i][j] = prompt(questions[i][j]); // ask the question at the position (i,j)
    }
}
```

What we did here was to create a matrix of questions (i.e.: an array of an array), which will allow us to perform the nested loop.

- In the 1st step of the loop we have `i=0` and `j=0`, then, `questions[0][0] == "Enter Guess First Name."`.
- In the 2nd step of the loop we have `i=0` and `j=1`, then, `questions[0][1] == "Enter Guess Last Name."`.
- In the 3rd step of the loop we have `i=1` and `j=0`, then, `questions[1][0] == "Enter Guess Phone."`.
- In the 4th step of the loop we have `i=1` and `j=1`, then, `questions[1][1] == "Enter Guess Guess Address."`.

And the end of the nested loops `myArray` will be filled with the responses of the questions asked on each step.

Comment: Hint: that is not the reason why the prompt only shows up once.

Comment: Is there a way that I can use two loop to collect the data for this? because my assignment require nested loop.

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible implementation. I don't like it, but it copes with the nested loop requirement.